# ReactJS UseEffect memory leak error - what is causing it?

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks, socket.io, axios

This is my first project using React Hooks. Today I encountered a memory leak issue - my app gives me this error:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

I have researched some solutions. For instance, I could track the state of my component using a variable 
`isMounted`.

The only problem is, I'm not entirely sure where I would implement this. As an example, I have 3 `UseEffect` hooks in one of my components. This particular component is among others that the memory leak error are attributed to.

**UseEffect 1:**

```
 useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("allLobbyClients", clients => {
      if (readyList.length == clients.length) {
        socket.emit("gameStarting", activeGamePin);
        socket.on("gameStartingMsg", data => {
          updateGameStarting(data);
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
          navigate("/game-draw", true);
        }, 5000);
      }
    });
  }, [readyList]);
```

**UseEffect 2:**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("readyClientIndexes", indexes => {
      updateReadyList(indexes);
    });
  }, []);
```

**UseEffect 3:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit("joinRoom", activeGamePin);
    socket.emit("getClientsForLobby", activeGamePin);
    socket.on("allLobbyClients", data => {
      //Gets the 'Client Index', which can be used to identify them in the <ol> when they specify they are ready to start the game.
      let clientName = window.localStorage.getItem("clientName");
      updateClientIndex(data.indexOf(clientName));
      let activePlayers = data.map((client, index) => (
        <li
          id={index}
          key={index}
          className={readyList.includes(index) ? "ready" : "unready"}
        >
          {client}
        </li>
      ));
      updateClientList(activePlayers);
    });
  }, [readyList]);
```

I also have a function that uses Axios to make a POST request.

```
  function playerIsReady() {
    let gamePin = activeGamePin;
    axios
      .post(`${backend}/newIndex`, {
        clientIndex: clientIndex,
        gamePin: gamePin
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      });
    setTimeout(() => {
      socket.emit("playerReady", gamePin);
    }, 2000);
    socket.on("readyClientIndexes", indexes => {
      updateReadyList(indexes);
      updateReadyBtn("invisible");
    });
  }
```

My primary question is: where is the memory leak error likely coming from? Does it originate from one of my useEffect hooks OR is it coming from the Axios function? For the first time in a while, I feel totally helpless in coming up with a solution.

Any replies are greatly, greatly appreciated - thank you in advance!

P.S. I suspect the error is related to the Axios function because memory leak errors have occurred in a component of my app that DOES NOT utilize a UseEffect hook. Hence, I am stuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that you need to unsubscribe from a `socket` subscriptions. Commonly it is done in `useEffect` cleanup function (`return () => {...}`)

#### Update

Once you implement `isMounted` add conditional check in front of each place where you are setting state async: `isMounted && setSomeState(..)`

Answer (score 1):

Without running the code, I might look at all the work the sockets are doing.  You set them up to do work, but there's nothing to shut them down after the component unmounts.  Consider cleaning them up in the function you can return from useEffect.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a particular way I can clean up the sockets in the return function?